# How can I add Permissions attribute to code signed JAR?

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner

I have a jar-file which is code signed. When I try to start the application with Java Web Start I get a warning that the `Permissions` attibute is missing in the manifest.

I removed the `*RSA` and `*SH` files from the META-INF folder and added the following attributes to the manifest:

- Permissions: all-permissions
- Codebase: *
- Application-Name: application

Then I signed the jar-file using the jarsigner. When I try to start the application I get a error message that the application is blocked, because of security settings. After changing the security settings to `medium` I can start the application, but the publisher is unknown.

What can I do, so that the publisher is not unkown?

Comment: can you provide the version of the jdk you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer to this topic would be concerning the new security restrictions for Java (so, depending on your version, and in this case of a webstarted app,also the client's version).

See [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) as a starting point.

Anyway, from what you describe, and ask, there are basically two ways so that the publisher "is not unknown".

a) Use a "trusted issuer". This means, acquiring a code signing certificate from a known (to Java) Certification Authority. 
This also means, in many cases, buying it from them (you could explore some dev options not for production use).

When you own a certificate like that, you repeat the signature process, and if you choose a CA Java has on-board (ex: Thawte, Symantec/Verisign,etc), you,as the signer, will be "known".

b) As I understand, you are using a *self-signed certificate*.

In this case (a little cumbersome and unsafe ) you could *install you self-signing CA certificate* into the executing JRE trust store (keystore). For this you should use the keytool java tool and have a little experience with PKI jargon.
The biggest drawback of this approach is that this requires an action on the client platform (writing files,etc), even if one-shot, this is not feasible usually (unless manageable/restriced area, such as intranets)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use a certificate from a CA. Without permissions attribute, the publisher is correct.

Comment: mmhh.... can you provide your JNLP file or verify that also inside it there's a security tag set to to "all-permissions" ?